# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL using C++

Tags: c++, macos, postgresql

I am trying to run PostgreSQL on my mac. PostgreQL itself works fine and I can create database and table and stuff but when I try to connect to PostgreSQL using C++ with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>

int     main() {
PGconn          *conn;
PGresult        *res;
int             rec_count;

conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=ljdata host=localhost user=dataman);

if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
 puts("We were unable to connect to the database");
exit(0);
} 

res = PQexec(conn, "update people set phonenumber=\'5055559999\' where id=3");
```

and compile with something like:

```
g++ -lpq db.cpp -o db
```

I get the error 
    ld: library not found for -lpq

and if I compile without lpq, I get

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_PQclear", referenced from:
      _main in ccpjNCAU.o
      _main in ccpjNCAU.o"
```

I have already included the libpq-fe.h, shouldn't it work? Does anybody know what went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ can't find the `pq` library.  You have to specify where to look for it, with a capital `-L`:

```
g++ -L/path/to/pq/lib -lpq db.cpp -o db
```

where `pq` is /path/to/pq/lib/libpq.a  (or whatever the extension is)

Here's what you probably want to do:

1. change the include line to not have the path.

   ```
   #include "libpq-fe.h"
   ```
2. Add the include path to the commandline

   ```
   g++ -I/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include db.cpp
   ```
3. Build intermediary object files

   ```
   g++ -I/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include db.cpp -c -o db.o
   ```
4. Link it together as a separate step

   ```
   g++ -L/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib db.o -lpq
   ```
5. Build with debug info using `-g`

Put it all together, for two separate build steps:  compile and link:

```
g++ -I/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include db.cpp -c -g -o db.o
g++ -L/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib db.o -lpq -o db
```

Comment: So if my file is in home, I should just do g++ -L/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/libpq-fe.h? That doesn't work either.

Comment: -L/path/to/lib/dir not /path/to/header/file.  Where is libpq located?

Comment: libpq-fe.h and libpq-events.h are in Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/ but there is one more, "libpq-fs.h" in Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/libpq

Comment: those are header files - they end in `.h`.  Where is the actual library file?

Comment: try looking in `Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib`  is it there?  If so, try compiling with `-L~/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib`

Comment: Ah now I understand you!! Yeah, they are in Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib but still g++ -L~/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib db.cpp -o db doesn't work. Furthermore, it says ld: warning: directory '~/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/' following -L not found. So, I tried g++ -L/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib db.cpp -o db and it still doesn't work!!

Comment: You seem to be using `/Library` which is from the root, instead of `~/Library` which would be under your home directory.  I've updated my answer with detailed explanations for building your code.  See if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the expkanation! However, it still doesn't compile. It now gives ld: warning: in /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/libpq.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "_PQclear", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
      _main in test.o

Comment: I think it is a version problem. But the one click installer of
postgresql for mac os X installs only a 32 bit version of the database, how do I install the 64 bit version?

Comment: @Confused, here's a resource page about building with pq:  http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/libpq-build.html

Comment: @Confused, what do you get if you run `pg_config --includedir` and `pg_config --libdir`?

Comment: I just get /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include and /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib

Comment: @Confused, a little googling confirms that this is a 32vs64 bit problem.  Yes, the one-click installer only includes 32-bit.  Apparently, PostGres's response is "download the source and build a 64-bit version yourself".  Which is almost as rude as "go f*** yourself".  You can get [the source here](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.4.6/), and supposedly it's "easy to build".  But I haven't tested that.

Comment: Hmm... everything seems to be the same as what is mentioned in the link you provided and I didn't forget to add -lpq either but I get ld: warning: in /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib/libpq.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "_PQclear", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
      _main in test.o

Answer (score 0):

`libpq-fe.h` is a user library, not a system library, and therefore you should use `"..."` instead of `<...>`, like this:

```
#include "/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/libpq-fe.h"
```

Take a look at [this link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html). And make sure `libpq-fe.h` can actually be found by your compiler.

Comment: I think my compiler can find libpq-fe.h. Once I change #include "/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/libpq-fe.h" to #include "Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/libpq-fe.h", I get  error: ‘PGconn’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘conn’ was not declared in this scope. As PGconn has been defined, doesn't that mean the libpq-fe.h can be found by the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, You need to add the path of the library to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, do it and you'll see. 
Good luck