# Why am getting compiler errors when I including Qt QThread and PostgreSQL libpq-fe header files?

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

Am getting weird compiler errors when I include these two header files in my source:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
```

This is how I have included the PostgreSQL library in my Qt project file:

```
win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/' -llibpq
else:unix: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/' -llibpq

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include'
```

This is one of the errors am getting:

```
d:\mingw\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\thread:282: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type' {aka 'ptw32_handle_t'} and 'std::thread::native_handle_type' {aka 'ptw32_handle_t'})
In file included from ..\threadtest\mainwindow.cpp:4:
d:\mingw\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\thread: In function 'bool std::operator==(std::thread::id, std::thread::id)':
d:\mingw\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\thread:282:26: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type' {aka 'ptw32_handle_t'} and 'std::thread::native_handle_type' {aka 'ptw32_handle_t'})
  282 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                |                |
      |                |                std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}
      |                std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}
```

What setting might I be missing?

Comment: Since MinGW wraps threads with its own machinery, its possible that you could be mixing 32 and 64 bit paradigms.  See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334728/link-error-with-libpq-using-c?rq=1

Comment: @Den-Jason good suggestion, however, MinGW am using is for a 64-bit platform.

Comment: A simple workaround would be to write said operator :)